# Trouble with type mismatch with TBCDField and TfmtBCDfield and oracle compatibility

Tags: delphi, oracle11g

I am converting a large application from Delphi 6 to Delphi 2009.

It was built originally to use Oracle 8i but now needs to use to Oracle 11g. The original application is quite happily using oracle 11g and will do so if I rebuild it using Delphi 6.

To get over some character set / character display problems and other minor annoyances with the application that have developed over the last 11 years, I decided to rebuild it in a later version of Delphi (Which has also been delayed for a couple of years hence using 2009.) which was bought for the purpose. I have now defeated the 550+ Compiler Warnings about this and that and the other.

But now almost every table/dataset I try to open against my test oracle 11g database reports "Type Mismatch for field 'xxxxxx' Expecting BCD actual FmtBCDField.

Is there a way around this without opening all 80+ datamodules that will **guarantee** compatibility with the clients database installation? I don't mind changing them all but I can't test it against the live database without a lot of messing about and don't want to do it only to get the opposite error at the client's site!

These are nearly all persistent fields in TClientDataSets connected to ADO queries but are accessed by using FieldByName in (again nearly) all cases.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi, I got the same problem. Just a suggestion : first, try to run executable application and check whether the problem persists. sometimes it run well on executable but get some errors while debugging. second, you said using ADO. I guess it uses ODBC driver for oracle 11g. Maybe the problem is that ODBC driver or ADO itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I needed my DBXpress application to work with both Oracle 9 and 11. For some reason DBXpress recognizes some NUMBER fields in different ways depending on the Oracle database version. I worked around it by casting the number fields to bigger number fields and changing BCD fields for FMTBCD fields in all my queries, the cast forced DBXpress to recognize every NUMBER as a FMTBCD since BCD couldn't support such big numbers, maybe it'll work on ADO too.